# How do I ppa-purge Bodhi Linux?

Tags: package-management, ppa

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 x64, and I wanted to try the enlightenment wm. I installed it and it was alright, but really not my cup of tea. I uninstalled it, but it also updated some of the packages that were already installed on my system. Naturally `ppa-purge` is what I need to use in this situation. Unfortunately, I'm not sure exactly how to use this on a non-launchpad repository.

I can't remember what tutorial/article I used, but I manually added `deb http://packages.bodhilinux.com/bodhi trusty main` to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Now reading the man page for `ppa-purge`, I thought the command that would do the trick is `sudo ppa-purge -p bodhi -s packages.bodhilinux.com`, but it's not working correctly and every other variation I try doesn't seem to work either. (It's just displaying the CLI help page).

I'm clearly not doing this right and I can't seem to be able to get the command right. Can anyone point me back in the right direction (what am I not doing correctly)? Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

ppa-purge will not work for you.

If you manually added that line to your /etc/apt/sources.list file you must manually delete that line from the file and then run the following command to update your package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, run

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

---

here's an example:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

here's another example:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

When the file opens, locate the line "deb http://packages.bodhilinux.com/bodhi trusty main", delete the line or comment it out and save the file before closing the file. Then, run `sudo apt-get update`.

---

One way to find out what packages need to be downloaded it to run the following command:

```
dpkg -l | grep <whateveryouwanttosearchfor>
```

example:

```
dpkg -l | grep bodhi1
```

The subsequent output will list all the packages that need to be downgraded.

---

Also, this command will list all the bodhi packages installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep bodhi
```

To uninstall all those packages with one command run the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge bodhi*
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge bodhi-*
```

---

edit: as provided by BCqrstoO

Open synaptic and select the "origin" filter on the left to determine which packages need to be downgraded.

Comment: Will this allow me to downgrade the packages that were updated because of this source? Or will that have to be something I figure out and do manually?

Comment: @BCqrstoO if you would like to downgrade the packages, you can type `apt-cache show <packagename> | grep Version:` replacing <packagename> with the actual package name. To install a specific version, use `sudo apt-get install <packagename>=<versionnumber>`

Comment: I'm going to select this as the accepted answer, but it still needs more instruction. For myself, in order to find the packages that were actually installed from `packages.bodhilinux.com` I actually had to pull up synaptic and select the `origin` filter on the left before I knew which packages I needed downgrade. Thank you for the other information.